# Join of two preorders and of two equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm sorry for the silly doubt. What is the join of two preorders? And of two equivalence relations? The meet is given by intersections. But in general the union of two preorders (resp. equivalence relations) fails to be a preorder (resp. equivalence relations). In the case of equivalence relation, is it the transitive closure of their union?

Comment: I'm assuming it's the smallest pre-order that contains both. for example the infinite meet in the frame of open sets is given by the interior of the intersection of the open sets. Since you have arbitrary intersecitons of pre orders are preorders you can define it analogously

Comment: Ok, but concretely, what is it? If you see the case of equivalence relations, we taking the transitive closure, which has a specific definition. What does it happen with preorders?

Comment: yeah it would be the "transitive closure" since the condition that fails in the union is not being reflexive (The diagonal remains in the union). I don't know how you have the transitve closue defined but you take the intersection of all transitive relation that contain the union. similar to how you would define the subgroup generated by a set S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, any poset which has all meets also has all joins. Proof: the join of the set $S$ is the meet of the set $\{x | \forall s \in S, s \leq x\}$.

So in this case, the join of two preorders $a, b$ is just the intersection of all pre-orders containing both $a$ and $b$.

Similarly, the join of two equivalence relations $a, b$ is just the intersection of all pre-orders containing both $a$ and $b$.

It turns out that in both of these cases, the transitive closure of the union of $a$ and $b$ is the join.

For if $a, b$ are reflexive, then the transitive closure of $a \cup b$ is also reflexive.

And if $a, b$ are symmetric, then $a \cup b$ is symmetric, and thus the transitive closure of $a \cup b$ is symmetric.

Comment: I may be wrong but in your first sentence the set $\{x ...\}$ may be empty I believe you need the condition that they have an upper bound. For example $\{a,b,c\}$ st $a\leq c$ and $a\leq b$ has all the meets but doesn't have the join between $a$ and $b$

Comment: @aldodecristo If all subsets have meets, then the empty set has a meet, which is necessarily the top element, so the set mentioned in the answer is not empty.